# Through link open the app Fragment page is not working Android

Tags: android

I want to open the App through the link which is present in my SMS and click on the link server will redirect me to (MyApp://?screen=upgrade) then I have to open the App.

Package name:- atul.com.applink

Android min version 19 I am using I want to open the Fragment page A

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="atul.com.applink" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Android host should not package name , host should be part of url

Answer (score 0):

The following XML snippet shows how you might specify an intent filter in your manifest for deep linking. The URIs “example://gizmos” and“http://www.example.com/gizmos” both resolve to this activity.

```
    <activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: my link is in (MyApp://?screen=upgrade) so in scheme we have write "myapp" in lowercase and in host "screen=upgrade"

Comment: in click of of URL i will get the JSON object in that i will get   (MyApp://?screen=upgrade)  so in manifest file i have to write only <data android:scheme="MyApp"
              android:host="screen=upgrade" /> plz help me out

Comment: sorry for above comment just want to ask In click of URL server will redirect me to these URL  (MyApp://?screen=upgrade)  so in manifest file i have to write only <data android:scheme="MyApp"
              android:host="screen=upgrade" /> plz help me out